# Determining where a bash function was defined

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I'm on a proprietary server; I know nothing about it. There's a bash function we use routinely to describe the server but if I write a bash script that uses that function it won't work.

So I want to load the original source file in the script. Is there a way to determine the location of the source file besides a "brute-force" search approach?  If I do `type -a thefunction` I can see the definition but not where it was sourced from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information isn't readily available. What may help is to start an interactive login shell with debugging (set -x) enabled. This will show you the source process in detail.

```
bash -ilx
```

When I initiate a bash shell like this, I see something like the following:

```
+++ . /etc/bash_completion.d/dd
++++ have dd
++++ unset -v have
++++ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
```

This shows me that when . /etc/bash_completion/dd was sourced, PATH was modified (or possibly re-set to the same values).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'Making xtrace more useful' section of http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips/

I tried adding the following near the top one of my scripts, and it looks like it gives the filename/line numbers for function calls.

```
set -x
export PS4='+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'
```

I tested on a CentOS 6.2 host with bash 4.1.2

Comment: You missed the point. I don't know where that function resides so there's no modifying the script to trace those details. If I write my own the function call fails because the referenced script isn't automatically sourced. Interesting info but you're answering a different question.